# Callback to Java method from c++

Tags: java, visual-c++, java-native-interface

Here is my situation and it's a bit complicated, but it has to be this way. I'm implementing a program from Java that open an application by using JNative. The application is written in C++. But when the application is finished I want it to callback to Java to let Java knows that the run is finished. Can I do that and how? I know I should use JNI but I found no example about that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

By "open an application" do you mean launch an external process, or make a library call?

If you're just launching an executable, you can use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec` to launch the process, and use the returned process handle to get the return code from the process. You can also capture the output of the process with `getInputStream` from the process you launched.

However, if you are actually calling into the C process, then yes, JNI would be a preferred solution. You can find a good tutorial on JNI calls back to Java object here: http://journals.ecs.soton.ac.uk/java/tutorial/native1.1/implementing/method.html

The crux of it from the tutorial is this:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_Callbacks_nativeMethod(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jint depth)
{
  jclass cls = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, obj);
  jmethodID mid = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, cls, "callback", "(I)V");
  if (mid == 0)
    return;
  printf("In C, depth = %d, about to enter Java\n", depth);
  (*env)->CallVoidMethod(env, obj, mid, depth);
  printf("In C, depth = %d, back from Java\n", depth);
}
```

In short, from C you need to get the method before you can call it. You can also use the javap tool to generate method signatures so you can call them.